# How does $resource service receive data from controller?

Tags: angularjs

I am in the learning phase of AngularJs and I was going through a sample project which implements REST. In this project an AngularJs controller calling `addEmployee()` method of `$resource` service, and sending an `employee` object through method's argument .

```
empDetailService.addEmployee($scope.employee, function() {
                    //some_code
            });
```

The `addEmployee()` is then posting that `employee` object to the server. I am not able to understand how `$resource`'s `addEmployee()` method is receiving that `employee` object from controller and sending it to the `url` mentioned , in `addEmployee()` only `url` and `method` is mentioned.

If any one can throw some light on working of `$resource`, that would be a great help. The code is working fine.

This is the controller code:

```
angularpoc.controller('addEmployeeController', function($scope, $resource,
        empDetailService, transferService) {
        $scope.addEmployee = function() {
        empDetailService.addEmployee($scope.employee, function() {
                //some_code
        });

    };

});
```

and this is the code for service:

```
angularpoc.service('empDetailService', function($resource) {

    return $resource('', {}, {
         addEmployee : {
            method : 'POST',
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/AngularPOC/addEmp'
        }

    });
});
```